# How to check which thread is currently locking static variable

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized, java.util.concurrent

I have class A and class B

```
class A{

static B b;

public static synchronized init(){
  b = new B();
}

public static doSomething(){
   init();

   synchronized(b){ // thread gets stuck after calling this

   }
}

}
```

Consider class A is a part of big application which might be calling init() method from somewhere. The problem is the thread is stuck at synchronized(b) block. It seems like someone is holding lock of class B? Is there any way to check which thread is holding lock of class B?

Comment: Thread.currentThread().getName

Comment: @Silentsudo..The coded is stuck at synchronized block means the class B is locked by some other thread than the current thread, in that case how your solution will give correct result?

Comment: 'Static instance variable' is a contradiction in terms. Take a thread dump. And cut down what happens inside the `synchronized` block so it doesn't take appreciable amounts of time.

Comment: But why are you initializing `b` every time through this method? You should only initialize it once, and you don't need an `init()` method for that, just an initializer in the declaration. This code cannot work as required as is.

Comment: @user207421.. I am not initializing every time in the real code, it is actually a Spring bean. I can not post actual code here for some reasons. Also, your suggestion for thread dump worked for me. doSomething() is being multiple times and the very first doSomething() call is stuck at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0 for some reason. Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: It will block reading the socket while there is no data.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether you can post the real code, but you should not post code doing things fundamentally different. In the code you’ve posted, the `b` variable is overwritten with a new object in a non-thread-safe way, each time `doSomething()` is called. This combines several possible outcomes, including having no thread safety at all but still getting deadlocks. There’s no sense in posting this and asking “what’s happening here” and then saying “but my code is not even remotely like this”.